# how to make the handle button of the SlidingDrawer launch from the left android

Tags: android

i work on app and want to make the sliding-drawer button launch from the left or the right of the screen i tried many things but its still shown in the center

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this type of behavior by nesting the button of your SlidingDrawer inside a Relative layout like so:

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content" 
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Handle"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

And then use android:layout_alignParentRight (or alignParentLeft) ="true" to move to button to the desired side.

I know, kind of a hacky solution, but hey that's life as an Android developer.

Hope this helps

Comment: its still on the center but thank you for the respond

Comment: Please see my edit. I forgot to move the:
android:id="@+id/handle"
from the Button to the RelativeLayout. It should work now, let me know if it does not

Comment: yea its working now thank you so much again for the respond :)